# Dotfucator Community giving "Build Error" Issue for Xamarin Forms android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, dotfuscator

I have been using dotfucator community version for Xamarin.Forms, which was working fine until last few days. Now Its giving Build Error. I have tried all suggested approaches in other threads of StackOverFlow but none are working. Pasting the last few lines of the logs below. Please help me out! This happens after an hour of processing.

```
LOG: Checking NuGet Folder : C:\Users\dibya\.nuget\packages\tizen.net\5.0.0.14562\build\tizen40\ref
LOG: Probing C:\Users\dibya\.nuget\packages\tizen.net\5.0.0.14562\build\tizen40\ref\System.Runtime.dll
LOG: Strong name match failed
LOG: Probing C:\Users\dibya\.nuget\packages\tizen.net\5.0.0.14562\build\tizen40\ref\System.Runtime.ni.dll
LOG: Probing C:\Users\dibya\.nuget\packages\tizen.net\5.0.0.14562\build\tizen40\ref\System.Runtime\System.Runtime.ni.dll
LOG: Not found in NuGet folders.
LOG: Checking additional folder : C:\Users\dibya\AppData\Local\Temp\Dotfuscator_20624\~MobileA.0
LOG: Probing C:\Users\dibya\AppData\Local\Temp\Dotfuscator_20624\~MobileA.0\System.Runtime.dll
LOG: Probing C:\Users\dibya\AppData\Local\Temp\Dotfuscator_20624\~MobileA.0\System.Runtime\System.Runtime.dll
LOG: Checking additional folder : C:\Users\dibya\AppData\Local\Temp\Dotfuscator_20624\~MobileA.1
LOG: Probing C:\Users\dibya\AppData\Local\Temp\Dotfuscator_20624\~MobileA.1\System.Runtime.dll
LOG: Probing C:\Users\dibya\AppData\Local\Temp\Dotfuscator_20624\~MobileA.1\System.Runtime\System.Runtime.dll
LOG: Not found in additional folders.
LOG: Loose binding enabled.  Probing for later versions.

Build Error.
```

I tried many threads from stackoverflow and some other community threads, but I am afraid by trying those I might complicate things as the logs are not very clear on what the issue is.

Comment: What has changed between the last time it was working and when it stopped working?

Comment: The only major change was addition of a nuget package and some code change following that. The nuget packages is https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/CardView

Comment: Are you sure this is directly related to Dotfuscator? Have you tried disabling Dotfuscator to see what happens? Can you still reproduce the error if you rollback those changes? The problem is that the error message doesn't really give useful hints, so you need to find out where and when the error occurs. If it is related to that nuget package, then you may need to include some additional files in the list of excluded items of Dotfuscator. Also one hour of processing is a long time for an XF app.

Comment: Yes this is directly related to Dotfuscator. If I disable it, the solution builds fine. The processing time is taken by dotfuscator to obsfucate the assemblies. Can you give me some hint on how I can exclude that nuget package from dotsfucator. I can give that a try. I also agree that the log is not useful at all. This log is directly taken from the dotfuscatorUI.exe.

Comment: Please add more information about your project and its dependencies to the question. By the way, did you follow the [Dotfuscator instructions for Xamarin.Forms](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/getting_started_xamarin.html)?

Comment: I am learning xamarin forms and built an audio player. There are few nuget packages which are included. And i followed the same link provided. Everything was working fine till a couple of days back and the only change was the inclusion of the nuget package and some code. I am trying myself to sort out the problem but unable to get the issue itself. Now running the build again and not sure why it is taking so much time. Not even sure if it's stuck or progressing. Bit frustrated.

Comment: If you're still learning Xamarin.Forms, then you should consider not using Dotfuscator yet. Is there anything worth protecting in your app that you really need to use it? I'm not using it in most of my app projects, either. Note that Microsoft will stop development and support of Xamarin.Forms in May of 2024. You should consider using its successor, [.NET MAUI](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/maui), instead.

Comment: Yeah probably i will disable the configuration for the dotfuscator for now. Yes i am aware about maui. I did some reading and people are saying it's not yet stable. I will migrate the code to maui. Thanks for your time!

Comment: It still has some quirks and issues, but it's getting better every week. And support will end in May next year and you won't even be able to release new apps using XF by the end of this year already once Xcode 15 was released.